# Looking for a way to create dynamic QR codes linked to 2 separate databases

Tags: php, mysql, qr-code

I'm a coding noob and I'm brainstorming on a project for work. I need a way to connect a dynamic QR code to two separate databases.

Here's how it would work:

- User signs up and enters personal information: Phone#, address, etc. **(Database A)** Let's call this person the owner.
- A unique dynamic QR is made for that particular user, updating itself if the account information ever changes **(Database A)**
- An authorized device scans it (only authorized devices should be able to activate the QR codes) and the following information is recoded automatically: location, time, and date **(Database B)**
- QR code *owner* is notified of scan via text **(Database A)**

Any help or advice would be very much appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: Are the two databases in the same mysql instance? If yes, then just use the databasename.tablename route to access the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing many concepts.
A QR code is just a mechanism to render data, so to simplify your problem, just ignore it and assume that instead of a QR code, you have a string representing the record on dB A.
If record in DB A changes, if you try to view it, of course it is changed.

Now the third point is unclear, if the qrcode is visible after accessing a secured page for example, you can log to DB B the information you can gather from the authorized user, but even if shown you can't tell if the qrcode was scanned or not.

Instead if you are the "owner" of the application which is meant to be used to scan the QRcode, then there after a successful scan, I would send for example an Ajax request to your service responsible to manage the data in DB B.

Whatever component you use to store data in DB B, can be used to invoke an action to ask another component to notify the user associated to the QR, for example using signalR.